# How do I set up user permissions on /var/www

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, webserver

Ubuntu 23.04

After a Fresh Install.
Im trying to set up the webserver so that my user account (artillery) can have 'rwx' priviledges on /var/www to create and edit files along with Apache (www-data)

I created a group called 'website' which has three members. root, www-data and artillery

```
$ sudo getent group website
website:x:1001:root,artillery,www-data
```

I then changed the ownership and priviledges on /var/www

```
$ sudo chown www-data:website  -R /var/www
$ sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
$ sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 665 {} +
```

and the the permissions look like this

```
$ pwd
/var/www/html
```

```
$ ls -al /var/www
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data website 4096 Jul 13 11:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root    4096 Jul 13 11:04 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data website 4096 Jul 13 11:04 html

$ ls -al /var/www/html
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data website  4096 Jul 13 11:04 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data website  4096 Jul 13 11:04 ..
-rw-rw-r-x 1 www-data website 10671 Jul 13 11:04 index.html

$ whoami
artillery
$ touch newfile
touch: cannot touch 'newfile': Permission denied
```

Can anybody explain why Im getting file permission errors?

I was hoping that having my user account 'artillery' as a member of group 'website' and having 'rwx' permissions would give me full permissions on the /var/www folder